# how to remove middle field in an object to access array inside it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

```
Map(3) {3 => 3, 2 => 3, 4 => 2}
      [[Entries]]
         0: {3 => 3}
         1: {2 => 3}
         2: {4 => 2}
size: 3
```

I want to access the array fields but I am not able to use [[entries]].
Here is a screenshot for better understanding. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PJgo.png)

Comment: This is a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map). You can loop through the entries `for(const [k,v] of mapObject) console.log(k,v)`. If you want to access a specific field, `map.get(2)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: The field [[entries]] is is the middle which is not allowing me access map values.

Comment: `[[entries]]` is not a field, it's the way the Chrome console displays Map. Map are not the same as object, see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: I have been able to access the fields individually but is there any way I can get this as a array like I have built it???
Can I access map as an Object???

Comment: You can get the entries of the map like `Array.from(map)` or `[...map]`